# Jquery - Build own plugin (error: is not a function)

Tags: jquery, plugins, callback

I'm trying to build my first jquery plugin but i get the following error:

> screenBlockis not a funnction

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function fiddletest()
{
    $.screenBlock({
       opacity: "0.4",
       zindex: "22",
       clickXXX: function(event){  alert('click'); }
    });

});

(function($){
$.fn.screenBlock = function(settings){

        // settings
        var config = {
            'opacity': 0.8,
            'z-index': 10
        };

        if ( settings ){$.extend(config, settings);}

        // Generate new selector
        var selector = 'sB_'+$.md5(appid+title+link+content)+'';

        // write screenBlocker DIV in body
        $('body').prepend('<div id="'+selector+'" style="background-color:#000000; opacity:'+config.opacity+';  margin:0px;  padding:0px;  position:fixed; display:none; left:0px;  top:0px;  width:100%;  height:100%; z-index:'+config.z-index+';"><div>');

        // Fade In
        $('#'+selector).fadeIn();

        // click on screenBlocker DIV,
        $('#'+selector).click(function (e)
        {
           // remove screenBlocker DIV
           $('#'+selector).remove();

           // destroy click
           $('#'+selector).unbind('click');

           // call function clickXXX
           // ... but how?

        });

        return selector;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

**example**
http://jsfiddle.net/ywHh8/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) two problems here.

First, you're calling `screenBlock()`in your first `ready` handler, which runs *before* you define that method in your second `ready` handler. You'll have to invert the two code blocks.

Second, you're calling the `screenBlock()` method on `$` itself, but you define it in the `$.fn` namespace, which means it should be called on a jQuery object:

```
$.screenBlock = function() {
    // This can be called with $.screenBlock().
};

$.fn.screenBlock = function() {
    // This can be called with $("selector").screenBlock().
};
```

Comment: Ok, it works now ( http://jsfiddle.net/ywHh8/7/ ). Can you tell me how i call the function clickXXX? Thank you very much for the fast answer.

Comment: Since that function is passed in your settings, you only need to do `settings.clickXXX();` (or `config.clickXXX();` since you extend `config` with `settings`).

Answer (score 1):

First, you should put your plugin code *before* you actually call it.  Typically, javascript is interpreted sequentially, so you need to put your plugin code before you call it.

Secondly, you should probably put your plugin code in its own file and source it with a script tag:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.screenBlock.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.screenBlock({
        opacity: "0.4",
        zindex: "22",
        click: function(event){ alert('click'); }
    });
});
</script>
```